# How to reference custom components in react-native?

Tags: react-native

So I have a custom component like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={this.props.buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

And I use the component like this:

```
class RootView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MyComponent/>
        <MyComponent/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The `RootView` is resizable. What I want to do is shrinking it's children `MyComponent` when `RootView` is small enough. And I need to shrink each `MyComponent` at a time: when `RootView` is small enough, shrink the first `MyComponent`, and when the first `MyComponent` reach a minimal size, shrink the second `MyComponent`.
I know there's `refs` in react-native, but it does not seem to work for custom component.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can add a ref to a custom component:

   `<Separator ref='sep' style={styles.offsetSeparator} />`

   [image]

So you should be able to do what you need.

2. However, when you find yourself having a strong dependency between different components, it means that it's probably a good time to start using Flux or something similar and then hold the data in a Store which will hold all the information needed for all 3 components. More about Flux here: https://facebook.github.io/flux/